How to monitor just specific type of URLs in google analytics 4?
How to monitor count of views, average spend time, bounce rate and other parameters for just specific type of URL in a google analytics 4,
e.g.
all URLs which start with domain.com/tag/
this mean e.g.
domain.com/tag/lol
domain.com/tag/sport

Easiest way to do this would be to create a custom report in Explorer. Use Page Location or Page Pathas your main dimension and apply the appropriate metrics.
In the filters, you need to filter whichever you choose and use matches regex and use this filter:
domain\.com\/tag.*.
This should work out of the box for Page Path but if you use location you either need to put .* at the beginning as a wildcard before or add the protocol.
This will capture all urls within the /tag directory. If you need to have specific ones you will need to add a capture group to the expression.

I follow your steps and make this config but there is no data, can you please check photo?

https://postimg.cc/4K1SF39R

It's not going to show anything until you add a metric. I suggest active users to start. You will probably need to add some additional dimensions and filters to drill down to something specific.

what more I need to add and how this look? I need info for just specific url in this case: /tag/

In the report, there are three things you will need to do: Add dimensions, metrics, and filters. You already have a dimension in the page location. You will need to add a metric (active users, event count, views, etc). By adding both of these to the page, you should see data show up. If there isn't, then you don't have data in your GA4. Once you see data, then you can apply the filter I previously talked about on the page location or path dimension(s).  Here is Google's doc on Explorer Reports: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7579450?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

thank you! it is works!
